# Why do aluminum and air have low specific heats?

Tags: molecular-structure, heat

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity#Factors_that_affect_specific_heat_capacity),

> ...specific heat capacity is a function of the structure of the substance itself. In particular, it depends on the number of degrees of freedom that are available to the particles in the substance; each independent degree of freedom allows the particles to store thermal energy. The translational kinetic energy of substance particles which manifests as temperature change is only one of the many possible degrees of freedom, and thus the larger the number of degrees of freedom available to the particles of a substance other than translational kinetic energy, the larger will be the specific heat capacity for the substance. For example, rotational kinetic energy of gas molecules stores heat energy in a way that increases heat capacity, since this energy does not contribute to temperature.

However, upon reading this, one question comes to mind. After doing some research, I found that found that aluminum and air relatively low specific heats (https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/specific-heat-capacity-d_391.html). This implies that aluminum and air have a low number of degrees of freedom. However, why is this the case? I know that air is mainly composed of $\ce{N2}$ and $\ce{O2}$ gas. Also, I know that aluminum has a crystal structure. Do these factors restrict the number of degrees of freedom? For example, I suppose that the crystal structure may restrict the rotational kinetic energy of each aluminum atom.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr They don't.**

You seek to explain one peculiar isolated fact from a bigger picture. When looking at the picture as a whole, the fact is neither isolated nor peculiar. It is the same as pointing at the guy in the background of "[Washington Crossing the Delaware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington_Crossing_the_Delaware)" and asking why is his head bandaged, and why is he wearing a fur coat and a funny hat; isn't all that strange? In a today's city street, maybe; but in the context of the broader picture, not at all.

Same thing here. Heat capacity of air is not particularly low, nor is it high. In fact, it is the same as that of any other diatomic gas, even though the table might seem to suggest otherwise. How so? Well, you already know that heat capacity is explained via degrees of freedom, but *what is it that has* those degrees of freedom? Guess what? It is **molecules**, not kilograms. So let's compare the comparable. Don't look at the heat capacity per kilogram. Look at the values per one molecule (or rather per one mole, which is the same, only without nasty $10^{\pm23}$s). Then you'll be able to verify what I said before.

Now to aluminum. Its heat capacity is not all that low. It is way higher than those of titanium, iron, copper, not to mention the heavier metals. It is, however, low when compared to water. Well, that's an expected thing: most solids have lower heat capacity than most liquids or gases. In particular, like you said, this is because the particles in a solid are less free to move, hence fewer degrees of freedom.

So it goes.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most important answer to your question is just that the densities of air and aluminum are low.  The relationship between the heat capacity and the availability of degrees of freedom in which energy can be stored requires you to compare equal number of degrees of freedom -- which is equal *moles* not equal *grams*.  Specific heat capacity is heat capacity *per gram*.  Anything with a low density will have fewer degrees of freedom per gram, by definition, and therefore a lower specific heat.

If you compare *molar* heat capacities, then Al is about the same as any other metal (e.g. Al 24.3 J/K-mol, Cu 24.5 J/K-mol) and not very different from air (e.g. N2 21 J/K-mol).  The real standout in molar heat capacities are substances like liquid water (75 J/K-mol).  The reason for this is that substances like liquid water have a lot of degrees of freedom that are frozen out at lower temperatures (meaning the minimum energy needed to excite them isn't available) and are becoming available at room temperature.  That means you can add in a lot of energy without changing the temperature much.  But this only happens under certain conditions.  At higher temperatures the molar heat capacity of H2O is unremarkable.

Comment: Why does water have so many more degrees of freedom than air or metals such as aluminum and copper? Do hydrogen bonds provide degrees of freedom? If so, how?

Comment: Be careful to distinguish between total number of degrees of freedom and dof that are available for energy storage without raising the temperature, which is what heat capacity measures.  *All* systems have the same total number of dof, 6N, where N = number of particles.  But some dof have low energy states that get "filled up" at low T, and you can't dump more energy into them without raising T.  Other dof have higher energy states that don't become accessible until higher T, and when these states "open up" it becomes possible to put a lot of energy in without raising T.

Comment: The most obvious example is at phase transitions, when a whole slew of dof "open up" and the heat capacity becomes very large until they're all "filled up."  Water in liquid state has a lot of dof that are just "opening up" so you can dump a lot of energy in without raising T.  (I'm putting phrases in "" here because to be precise about what's going on we need to get back to def'n of heat capacity C = T/N (dS/dT) and talk about how rate at which entropy increases when you dump extra energy in.)

Comment: What are the degrees of freedom that "open up" in liquid water?